# Using SubInACL to access Offline Files

Tags: file-permissions, offline-files

I'm trying to use SubInACL to access a **remote computer's** offline files share. This is a networked computer on our local domain.

I can see the files/folders by exploring `\\compname\c$\windows\csc` but can't access any folders in there unless I take ownership.

This is a laborious process in Windows so I've been using the SubInACL tool as follows:

- Download SubInACL from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23510
- Install it to "C:\SIACL"
- Run an elevated Command Prompt
- Navigate to the installation directory: cd "C:\SIACL"
- Run the following command to take ownership of the root directory: subinacl /file "\compname\c$\windows\csc" /setowner=Administrators
- Run the following command to take ownership of the other files: subinacl /subdirectories "\compname\c$\windows\csc*.*" /setowner=Administrators

In theory, I believe this should give the local Administrators group ownership over the Offline Files folder and all of its subdirectories and files. The domain's Domain Administrators group is part of the local Administrators group on all of our machines, and my user account is in the Domain Administrators group. As such, I should be able to access all of these files.

However... I can't! On one machine I tried, this worked fine. On another, I couldn't even access the first subdirectory (`v2.0.6`) in the `CSC` folder.

Is my syntax wrong? Or do I need to `/grant` permissions as well as taking ownership?

Comment: Why do you need to access the offline file cache?

Comment: To retrieve some files.